# Narrow down primitive return type of function at call site in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Writing a function that can take an `any` value and returns only `boolean` or `number` in typescript, it all works fine, until we need to narrow down the return value of the function at the call site to suit some variable type(or parameter type in case of functions compositions)

Here's the function

```js
function parseValue(value: any, defaultValue: number | boolean): number | boolean {

    const valueType = typeof value;


    switch (valueType) {
        case 'undefined': {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        case 'boolean': {
            return value;
        }

        default: {

            if (value == 'Unlimited')
                return Infinity;

            return parseInt(value);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is seen at call site

```js
let booleanResult = parseValue(true, true);

// Error: type boolean | number is not assignable to type boolean
let booleanCondition: boolean = booleanResult;


let numberResult = parseValue(2, 1);

// Error: type boolean | number is not assignable to type number
let numberValue: number = numberResult;
```

##### Is there a way in typescript which allow us to specify the return type at call site?

---

Overloading is not compatible!
It looks like I can't make on overload a function with different param type(correct me if I'm wrong here)

```js
type returnType = boolean | number;

// This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature

function parseValue(value: any, defaultValue:  boolean):  returnType;
function parseValue(value: any, defaultValue: number ): returnType{
 ...
}
```

---

I know we can parse the output of the function again to make it works like:

```js
let numberValue: number = Number(numberResult);
```

But I'm looking for a `typescript` solution for this problem.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

Comment: I've tried that and updated the question, thank you anyway

Comment: That's not how overloads work. Re-read the docs, you'll have at least two overload signatures _and_ the implementation. Also I thought the point was to be more specific about the return types?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I was using overload wrongly, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use typescript overload the proper way:

From [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

> The signature of the implementation is not visible from the outside. When writing an overloaded function, you should always have two or more signatures above the implementation of the function.

The solution was easily done writing each overload function alone, then writing the body of the function

```js
function parseValue(value: any, defaultValue: number): number;
function parseValue(value: any, defaultValue: boolean): boolean;
function parseValue(value: any, defaultValue: number | boolean): boolean | number {
 ... body of function
}
```

My problem was solved when I've read

> Again, the signature used to write the function body can’t be “seen” from the outside.

##### So I was kind of merging the overload with the implementation, where we should have *separated* them